# iphone/ipad standard twitter oauth module?

Tags: iphone, ipad, twitter, oauth, popover

I have seen the following in a few different apps so it seems like some kind of public api. Anyone where I can find the code for this? Specifcally the twitter login that appears in the popover:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of OAuth needs to be better… OAuth is a way for users to sign into a service without revealing the credentials to the application. The interface you are seeing is Twitter's OAuth endpoint. I suggest looking into the [twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-FAQ) for integration help.

If you would like to program your own interface for collecting the users credential, use [XAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) instead.